# Firebase Firestore Securitty Rule based on Attribute Value

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am trying to write security rules on my Firestore database to allow read of documents within a collection with `status` value as `published`. But, it does not allow read for any document for the collection once the rule is published.

I am following the permission settings as described on the official doc. 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions

But, it is not working as expected.

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    match /articles/{articleId} {
        allow read: if resource.data.status == 'published';
    }
  }
}
```

---

I am using the following React + Redux code for querying the documents:

```
export const getArticles = (limit = 25) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: ARTICLES });

    const db = firebase.firestore();
    const query = db.collection('articles')
                    .orderBy('createdAt', 'desc')
                    .limit(limit);

    query.get()
    .then((snapshot) => {
      const dataArray = [];
      snapshot.forEach(doc => {
        dataArray.push(mergeDocIdAndData(doc.id, doc.data()));
      });
      getArticlesSuccess(dispatch, dataArray)
        .then(() => dispatch(push('/articles')));
    })
    .catch(() => getArticlesFail(dispatch));
  };
}
```

Comment: What is the code you are using to read the documents?

Comment: I am using React + Redux. The following gist contains the method for reading data.

https://gist.github.com/ishouvik/62d0f43974522b29f1ae3c4346862d22

Comment: @ShouvikMukherjee Can you please include the relevant code in your question? Currently the accepted answer and your question can seem completely unrelated.

Comment: @AndréKool good remark. Shouvik Mukherjee, I've added the code used for querying, from the gist linked above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have missed one specific point in the doc: your query fails "because it does not include the same constraints as your security rules" and "security rules are not filters". See https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#queries_and_security_rules

In other words, your query should be like:

```
const query = db.collection('articles').where("status", "==", "published")...
```

Comment: Oh okay. I missed that. Thank you so much for pointing that out. 

~ Cheers!

Comment: They also give the following rule `allow read: if resource.data.published == true || request.auth.uid == resource.data.author`. When I do `firebase.firestore().collection('test').where('published', '==', true).get()` I only get documents where `published == true` Is this as expected or should I also get documents from the logged in user where `published == false` which is what I want but I don't see them in the resultset.

Comment: @Guus It is as expected. Independently of the security rule you filter with  `where('published', '==', true)`. If you want all the docs for which you are author but are not published, you need to build another query and merge the two results. (it is not possible to do an OR)